# Evolution email forgets all settings after reboot

Tags: gnome, evolution, email

My Evolution email client keeps forgetting all settings after a reboot or even a logout/login.

I have recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 on a new laptop. To move my Evolution settings and email over to the new machine, I selected "backup", which creates a single tar.gz archive of all Evolution settings and mail. I copied the file to the new computer, started Evolution which presented me with the startup assistant. I selected 'restore from backup', pointed at the tar.gz file and all was beautifully restored. All seemed to work just fine.

However, after a reboot I noticed that Evolution seems to have forgotten all settings: I get the startup assistant again when I start Evolution. I checked that the `.conf/evolution` and `.local/share/evolution` directories were still present, yet, none of that seemed to matter, it wanted me to restore from a backup again.

The version of Ubuntu (12.04) and Evolution (3.2.3) are the same on the old and new laptop.

Just stopping and restarting Evolution does not cause this problem. Even if I manually kill all Evolution related processes, the settings will be remembered and it can start up no problem. The problem only happens on logout/login or reboot.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I just started using Evolution on 16.04 LTS, and noticed something similar the last time I rebooted...